Draw a car with TikZ
Original question
I have drawn a simple car with this code:
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \shade[top color=red, bottom color=white, shading angle={135}]
        [draw=black,fill=red!20,rounded corners=1.2ex,very thick] (1.5,.5) -- ++(0,1) -- ++(1,0.3) --  ++(3,0) -- ++(1,0) -- ++(0,-1.3) -- (1.5,.5) -- cycle;
    \draw[very thick, rounded corners=0.5ex,fill=black!20!blue!20!white,thick]  (2.5,1.8) -- ++(1,0.7) -- ++(1.6,0) -- ++(0.6,-0.7) -- (2.5,1.8);
    \draw[thick]  (4.2,1.8) -- (4.2,2.5);
    \draw[draw=black,fill=gray!50,thick] (2.75,.5) circle (.5);
    \draw[draw=black,fill=gray!50,thick] (5.5,.5) circle (.5);
    \draw[draw=black,fill=gray!80,semithick] (2.75,.5) circle (.4);
    \draw[draw=black,fill=gray!80,semithick] (5.5,.5) circle (.4);

   \shade[top color=red, bottom color=white, shading angle={135}]
   [draw=black,fill=red!20,rounded corners=1.2ex,very thick] (1.5,.5) -- ++(0,1) -- ++(1,0.3) --  ++(3,0) -- ++(1,0) -- ++(0,-1.3) -- (1.5,.5) -- cycle;
   \draw[very thick, rounded corners=0.5ex,fill=black!20!blue!20!white,thick]  (2.5,1.8) -- ++(1,0.7) -- ++(1.6,0) -- ++(0.6,-0.7) -- (2.5,1.8);
   \draw[thick]  (4.2,1.8) -- (4.2,2.5);
   \draw[draw=black,fill=gray!50,thick] (2.75,.5) circle (.5);
   \draw[draw=black,fill=gray!50,thick] (5.5,.5) circle (.5);
   \draw[draw=black,fill=gray!80,semithick] (2.75,.5) circle (.4);
   \draw[draw=black,fill=gray!80,semithick] (5.5,.5) circle (.4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

what should we do if we want to have 3 cars at a distance from each other?

Edit based on the answers
[![enter image description here][1]][1][![enter image description here][1]][1]I have drawn a simple car with this code:
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    pics/my car/.style={
        code={
            \tikzset{my car/.cd, #1}
            \shade[my car/car color, shading angle={135},
                draw=black, rounded corners=1.2ex, very thick] 
                (1.5,.5) -- ++(0,1) -- ++(1,0.3) --  ++(3,0) -- ++(1,0) 
                    -- ++(0,-1.3) -- (1.5,.5) -- cycle;
            \draw[very thick, rounded corners=0.5ex, fill=black!20!blue!20!white, thick]
                (2.5,1.8) -- ++(1,0.7) -- ++(1.6,0) -- ++(0.6,-0.7) -- (2.5,1.8);
            \draw[thick] (4.2,1.8) -- (4.2,2.5);
            \draw[fill=gray!50, thick] 
                (2.75,.5) circle[radius=.5cm]
                (5.5,.5) circle[radius=.5cm];
            \draw[fill=gray!80, semithick] 
                (2.75,.5) circle[radius=.4cm]
                (5.5,.5) circle[radius=.4cm];
            \coordinate (-front) at (1.5,1);
            \coordinate (-back) at (6.5,1);
            \coordinate (-top) at (4.25,2.5);
            \coordinate (-bottom) at (4.25,0);
        }
    },
    my car/car color/.style={
        top color=red, bottom color=white
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pic (car 1) at (0,0) {my car};    

\pic (car 2) at (10,0) {my car={car color/.append style={top color=blue}}};  

\pic (car 3) at (20,0) {my car={car color/.append style={top color=green}}};  

\pic (car 4) at (30,0) {my car={car color/.append style={top color=black}}};  

%\draw[<-, shorten <=5pt, shorten >=5pt, ultra thick] 
  %  (car 1-back) -- (car 2-front);

\draw[line width=5pt][<-, shorten <=5pt, shorten >=5pt] 
    (car 1-top) to[out=90, in=90] (car 2-top);
  \draw[line width=5pt][<-, shorten <=5pt, shorten >=5pt] 
  (car 2-top) to[out=90, in=90] (car 3-top);
   \draw[line width=5pt][<-, shorten <=5pt, shorten >=5pt] 
  (car 3-top) to[out=90, in=90] (car 4-top);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Just insert images for car in scope and than define distance between scopes. However, you may consider to draw car as small pictures pic. For details see tikz manual.

You could take other cars from this example

Make a \pic of it to reuse it.

Do not completely revise your question after having received answers. It is essential on this site that the answers relate to the question which is no more the case if you revise the question to much. I hence added your original question again. Apart from that, I suggest that you ask a new question.

If your question is how to separate the arrows so that they do not collide, you could shift the coordinate, for example using \draw[line width=5pt, <-, shorten <=5pt, shorten >=5pt] (car 1-top) to[out=90, in=90] ([xshift=-5pt]car 2-top); (or use another value for xshift).

@Jasper Habicht
I mean that the shape of my arrows should be the same as the original black arrows

Update:
To add arrows and others, You can do it as if they were nodes, obviously you have to define a specific point to leave and arrive, in this case in the drawing of the Texla car I added a point at the top, then it is a matter of playing with the commands from line to line and nodes in lines. Here is an example of what a basic application can be.
U-RESULT:

U-MWE:
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        >=Triangle
        ]
        %Start drawing the thing...
        % Help lines to plan where put all:
        \def\wcanvas{20}
        \def\hcanvas{6}
        \draw[red!5,step=0.25] (-1,-2) grid (\wcanvas,\hcanvas);
        \draw[cyan!40,step=1,line width=1] (-1,-2) grid (\wcanvas,\hcanvas);
        \foreach \x in {-1, ..., \wcanvas} {%
            \node[anchor=90] at (\x,-2) {\tiny\x};
        }
        \foreach \y in {-2, ..., \hcanvas} {%
            \node[anchor=0] at (-1,\y) {\tiny\y};
            
        }
        %Creating a weel for all cars
        \def\Weel#1{%\Weel{position}
            \draw[fill=white,shift={(#1)}](0,0)circle (0.3);
            \draw[fill=black!80, even odd rule,shift={(#1)}](0,0) circle (.5) circle (0.3);
            \draw[fill,shift={(#1)}](0,0) circle (0.05);
            \foreach \i in {1,...,12}{\draw[fill,shift={(#1)}](30*\i:0.15)--(30*\i:0.25)--+(90+30*\i:0.05);}        
        }
        
        \def\TexLaCAr#1#2#3#4[#5]{ %\OrigCAr{position}{orientation~restrcited~values~1~or~-1}{rotation}{color}[ID]
            \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)},xscale=#2,rotate=#3]
                \draw(0,0) coordinate (#5) circle (2pt);
                \draw(0.2,1.8) coordinate (#5-top);%<--Added a point on top named nodename-top
                
                \begin{scope}[x=1pt,y=-1pt,top color=#4,bottom color=black!50,xshift=-90,yshift=57]
                    \shadedraw%Path obtained using Inkscape and tikz path export complement https://github.com/xyz2tex/svg2tikz
                    (7.3, 17.6)
                    -- (96.6, 6.0) -- (153.1, 25.4) -- cycle;                               
                    \fill
                    (151.9, 24.4)
                    -- (157.7, 27.4) -- (157.2, 41.7) -- (119.9, 45.8) -- (29.2, 46.3)
                    -- (9.8, 39.5) -- (9.3, 35.7) -- (12.8, 35.7) -- (13.8, 20.6)
                    -- cycle;
                    \shadedraw
                    (7.3, 17.1)
                    -- (10.1, 34.2) -- (22.6, 35.5) -- (28.9, 25.1) -- (47.8, 25.1)
                    -- (56.6, 38.2) -- (120.7, 40.0) -- (128.5, 26.9) -- (146.9, 26.9)
                    -- (153.1, 36.7) -- (157.2, 36.7) -- (157.6, 27.6) -- (152.9, 26.8)
                    -- (152.9, 25.1) -- cycle;
                    \fill
                    (137.2, 22.0)
                    -- (96.2, 7.7) -- (63.5, 11.2) -- (62.9, 17.0) -- cycle;
                    \draw
                    (62.7, 17.2) -- (62.4, 20.4) -- (63.2, 38.7) -- (64.1, 45.6);
                    \draw
                    (90.9, 19.2) -- (91.4, 23.1) -- (92.7, 45.5);
                    \draw
                    (120.6, 21.2) -- (121.5, 24.0) -- (120.8, 45.4);
                \end{scope}
                \Weel{1.67,0.5}
                \Weel{-1.8,0.5}
                \ifnum#2=-1{\draw(0,0)++(0,2.5em)node[rotate=-#3]{\TeX \raisebox{-0.49ex}{L}A};}\fi
                \ifnum#2=1{\draw(0,0)++(0,2.5em)node[rotate=#3]{\TeX \raisebox{-0.49ex}{L}A};}\fi               
            \end{scope}
        }
        
        % drawing the Cars 
        \TexLaCAr{3,0}{1}{0}{white}[CAR-1]
        \TexLaCAr{$(CAR-1)+(6,0)$}{1}{0}{white!50!red}[CAR-2]
        \TexLaCAr{$(CAR-2)+(7,0)$}{1}{0}{white!50!blue!}[CAR-3]

        %using ARCS
        \draw[->](CAR-1-top) arc (180:0:2.9)node[pos=0.5, anchor=-90]{$t_1$};
        \draw[->](CAR-2-top) arc (180:0:3.4)node[pos=0.5, anchor=-90]{$t_2$};
        %Using controls
        \draw[->,red,dashed](CAR-1-top) .. controls ++(60:3) and ++(120:3) .. (CAR-2-top)node[pos=0.5, anchor=-90]{$t_1$};
        \draw[->,red,dashed](CAR-2-top) .. controls ++(60:3) and ++(120:3) ..(CAR-3-top)node[pos=0.5, anchor=-90]{$t_2$};
        \draw[->,blue,dashed,thick](CAR-1-top) .. controls ++(80:4) and ++(100:4) ..($(CAR-3-top)+(0.1,0)$)node[pos=0.5, anchor=-90]{$t_1+t_2$};
        %Draing some distances 
        \draw[|<->|,dashdotted,green!50!black, thick] (CAR-1)++(0,-0.3) -- ($(CAR-2)+(0,-0.3)$) node[midway,below]{6 su};
        \draw[|<->|,dashdotted,green!50!black, thick] (CAR-2)++(0,-0.3) -- ($(CAR-3)+(0,-0.3)$) node[midway,below]{7 su};
        \draw[|<->|,dashdotted,green!50!black, thick] (CAR-1)++(0,-0.9) -- ($(CAR-3)+(0,-0.9)$) node[midway,below]{7 su + 6 su = 13 su};
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


original:

Just for fun and adapt the example I had to your case, and indicate some important things to do that, the first thing is that you should try to draw with respect to an anchor point that is in the center of your drawing, so you can take advantage of mirroring it to change direction in this case; You can also define certain points and assign an ID for all cases; I leave the point 0.0 the coordinate of each drawing that can be named for later uses, also the point of the front of the car, in case you want to make a dimension between these.
Drawing things with complex shapes can be very complicated the way you do it by just looking at code, there are many ways to be able to have complex things like vehicles, you just have to resort to other free tools such as Inkscape, you can choose to open a file SVG and save it in PDF format, then import it to your drawing in a node using inglude graphics, scale it and add points or text; However, you will not be able to change colors, for example; For that, what you can do is make a tracing of paths, trying to keep them minimal, then export them using the extension to export these strokes to tikz.
The stroke that you will obtain in turn has to be adapted to the size of your drawing, luckily for this you can scale and move all the points using scope then nest them in the definitions, and well the rest is fixing things, fixing the code so that it can be read, etc. Ultimately you get a framework with which you can play with these as if they were stickers.
RESULT:

MWE:
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,math}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        %Start drawing the thing...
        % Help lines to plan where put all:
        \def\wcanvas{15}
        \def\hcanvas{12}
        \draw[red!5,step=0.25] (-1,-1) grid (\wcanvas,\hcanvas);
        \draw[cyan!40,step=1,line width=1] (-1,-1) grid (\wcanvas,\hcanvas);
        \foreach \x in {-1, ..., \wcanvas} {%
            \node[anchor=90] at (\x,-1) {\tiny\x};
        }
        \foreach \y in {-1, ..., \hcanvas} {%
            \node[anchor=0] at (-1,\y) {\tiny\y};
            
        }
        %Creating a weel for all cars
        \def\Weel#1{%\Weel{position}
            \draw[fill=white,shift={(#1)}](0,0)circle (0.3);
            \draw[fill=black!80, even odd rule,shift={(#1)}](0,0) circle (.5) circle (0.3);
            \draw[fill,shift={(#1)}](0,0) circle (0.05);
            \foreach \i in {1,...,12}{\draw[fill,shift={(#1)}](30*\i:0.15)--(30*\i:0.25)--+(90+30*\i:0.05);}        
        }
        %Creating a Macro to draw the original car
        \def\OrigCAr#1#2#3#4[#5]{ %\OrigCAr{position}{orientation~restrcited~values~1~or~-1}{rotation}{color}[ID]
            \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)},xscale=#2,rotate=#3]
                \draw(0,0) coordinate (#5) circle (2pt);
                \shadedraw[
                top color=#4,
                bottom color=white,
                shading angle={135},
                draw=black,
                fill=red!20,
                rounded corners=1.2ex,
                very thick,
                xshift=-40mm,%To center your draw to the anchor point at 0,0 to use as drawing block
                ]
                (1.5,.5)
                -- ++(0,1)
                -- ++(1,0.3)
                -- ++(3,0) 
                -- ++(1,0) 
                -- ++(0,-1.3)
                -- (1.5,.5) coordinate (#5-front) % You can define some points in the shape to use later
                -- cycle;
                \draw[very thick, rounded corners=0.5ex,fill=black!20!blue!20!white,thick,xshift=-40mm] 
                (2.5,1.8)
                -- ++(1,0.7)
                -- ++(1.6,0)
                -- ++(0.6,-0.7)
                -- (2.5,1.8);
                \draw[thick,xshift=-40mm,]  (4.2,1.8) -- (4.2,2.5);
                %\draw[draw=black,fill=gray!50,thick] (2.75,.5) circle (.5);
                \Weel{$(2.75,.5)+(-40mm,0)$}
                %\draw[draw=black,fill=gray!50,thick] (5.5,.5) circle (.5);
                \Weel{$(5.5,.5)+(-40mm,0)$}
                \ifnum#2=-1{\draw(0,0)++(0,2.5em)node[rotate=-#3]{#5};}\fi
                \ifnum#2=1{\draw(0,0)++(0,2.5em)node[rotate=#3]{#5};}\fi
            \end{scope}
        }
    
        \def\SuvCAr#1#2#3#4[#5]{ %\OrigCAr{position}{orientation~restrcited~values~1~or~-1}{rotation}{color}[ID]
            \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)},xscale=#2,rotate=#3]
                \def\CarLenght{5}
                \fill[black!50!#4](-\CarLenght/2.5,0.5) rectangle ++(\CarLenght*0.86,8mm);
                \Weel{\CarLenght*1.9/6,0.5}
                \Weel{-\CarLenght*1.45/6,0.5}
                \draw(0,0) coordinate (#5) circle (2pt);
                \begin{scope}[%this way to put optios allows you to add comments for each also enable or disble them
                    top color=#4,
                    bottom color=white,
                    shading angle={135+#3},
                    %opacity=0.5,%some dissabled option
                    x=1pt,%Must be the same as the unit value in tikz path export option
                    y=-1pt,%idem
                    scale=0.31,%To size all to the scale of the original car
                    xshift=-230,%To put all in the planned anchor for definition 
                    yshift=220%idem
                    ]
                    \shadedraw
                    (69.0, 179.9)%Path obtained using Inkscape and tikz path export complement https://github.com/xyz2tex/svg2tikz
                    .. controls (69.0, 179.9) and (65.4, 116.6) .. (118.8, 116.6)
                    .. controls (172.1, 116.6) and (171.4, 180.7) .. (171.4, 180.7)
                    -- (326.5, 179.2)
                    .. controls (326.5, 179.2) and (318.6, 115.9) .. (374.8, 115.9)
                    .. controls (431.0, 115.9) and (427.5, 180.7) .. (427.5, 180.7)
                    .. controls (427.5, 180.7) and (445.9, 182.8) .. (453.1, 175.7)
                    .. controls (460.2, 168.6) and (460.9, 135.8) .. (458.7, 133.0)
                    .. controls (456.6, 130.2) and (446.7, 118.8) .. (446.7, 118.8)
                    .. controls (446.7, 118.8) and (449.5, 98.2) .. (440.3, 91.0)
                    .. controls (431.0, 83.9) and (356.3, 80.4) .. (346.4, 74.0)
                    .. controls (336.4, 67.6) and (285.9, 23.5) .. (268.8, 15.6)
                    .. controls (251.8, 7.8) and (83.2, 8.5) .. (71.1, 14.2)
                    .. controls (59.0, 19.9) and (40.5, 69.7) .. (40.5, 69.7)
                    .. controls (40.5, 69.7) and (44.8, 46.9) .. (26.3, 46.2)
                    .. controls (7.8, 45.5) and (6.4, 56.2) .. (5.0, 83.9)% circle (3pt) %uncoment to see where is in the draw
                    .. controls (3.6, 111.7) and (4.3, 126.6) .. (14.9, 127.3)
                    .. controls (25.6, 128.0) and (32.0, 127.3) .. (32.0, 127.3)
                    .. controls (32.0, 127.3) and (21.3, 147.9) .. (30.6, 165.0)
                    .. controls (39.8, 182.1) and (69.0, 179.9) .. (69.0, 179.9)
                    -- cycle;
                    
                    \draw[fill=#4!80!white,rounded corners]
                    (168.6, 86.1)
                        -- (170.0, 22.0) -- (75.4, 22.8) -- (54.1, 88.2)
                        -- cycle;               
                    \draw[fill=#4!80!white,rounded corners]
                    (188.5, 22.8)
                        -- (187.8, 87.5) -- (328.6, 86.8) -- (262.4, 22.8)
                        -- cycle;       
                \end{scope}
                \ifnum#2=-1{\draw(0,0)++(0,2.5em)node[rotate=-#3]{#5};}\fi
                \ifnum#2=1{\draw(0,0)++(0,2.5em)node[rotate=#3]{#5};}\fi
            \end{scope}
        }
                
        \def\TexLaCAr#1#2#3#4[#5]{ %\OrigCAr{position}{orientation~restrcited~values~1~or~-1}{rotation}{color}[ID]
            \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)},xscale=#2,rotate=#3]
                \draw(0,0) coordinate (#5) circle (2pt);
                
                \begin{scope}[x=1pt,y=-1pt,top color=#4,bottom color=black!50,xshift=-90,yshift=57]
                    \shadedraw%Path obtained using Inkscape and tikz path export complement https://github.com/xyz2tex/svg2tikz
                    (7.3, 17.6)
                        -- (96.6, 6.0) -- (153.1, 25.4) -- cycle;                               
                    \fill
                    (151.9, 24.4)
                        -- (157.7, 27.4) -- (157.2, 41.7) -- (119.9, 45.8) -- (29.2, 46.3)
                        -- (9.8, 39.5) -- (9.3, 35.7) -- (12.8, 35.7) -- (13.8, 20.6)
                        -- cycle;
                    \shadedraw
                    (7.3, 17.1)
                        -- (10.1, 34.2) -- (22.6, 35.5) -- (28.9, 25.1) -- (47.8, 25.1)
                        -- (56.6, 38.2) -- (120.7, 40.0) -- (128.5, 26.9) -- (146.9, 26.9)
                        -- (153.1, 36.7) -- (157.2, 36.7) -- (157.6, 27.6) -- (152.9, 26.8)
                        -- (152.9, 25.1) -- cycle;
                    \fill
                    (137.2, 22.0)
                        -- (96.2, 7.7) -- (63.5, 11.2) -- (62.9, 17.0) -- cycle;
                    \draw
                    (62.7, 17.2) -- (62.4, 20.4) -- (63.2, 38.7) -- (64.1, 45.6);
                    \draw
                    (90.9, 19.2) -- (91.4, 23.1) -- (92.7, 45.5);
                    \draw
                    (120.6, 21.2) -- (121.5, 24.0) -- (120.8, 45.4);
                \end{scope}
                \Weel{1.67,0.5}
                \Weel{-1.8,0.5}
                \ifnum#2=-1{\draw(0,0)++(0,2.5em)node[rotate=-#3]{\TeX \raisebox{-0.49ex}{L}A};}\fi
                \ifnum#2=1{\draw(0,0)++(0,2.5em)node[rotate=#3]{\TeX \raisebox{-0.49ex}{L}A};}\fi
                
                
            \end{scope}
        }
          
        % drawing the Cars 
        \OrigCAr{3,9}{-1}{0}{green}[CAR-1]
        \OrigCAr{$(CAR-1)+(7,0)$}{1}{0}{cyan}[CAR-2]
        \SuvCAr{$(CAR-2)+(0,-5)$}{1}{0}{black}[CAR-3]
        \SuvCAr{$(CAR-1)+(0,-2)$}{-1}{135}{red!50!black}[CAR-4]
        \TexLaCAr{3,0}{1}{0}{white}[CAR-5]
        \TexLaCAr{$(CAR-5)+(7,1)$}{-1}{-15}{green!30!black}[CAR-6]
        
        %Draing some distances: Valid only for vertical or horizontal dimensions 
        \def\AcotX[#1][#2]#3#4{ %\AcotX[nodename_A][nodemame_b]{_known distance}{color}
            \draw[|<->|,draw=#4] (#1)++(0,-0.3) -- ($(#2)+(0,-0.3)$) node[midway,below]{#3 su};
        }
        \def\AcotY[#1][#2]#3#4{ %\AcotX[nodename_A][nodemame_b]{_known distance}{color}
            \draw[|<->|,draw=#4] (#1)++(-0.3,0) -- ($(#2)+(-0.3,0)$) node[midway,left]{#3 su};
        }
    
        \AcotX[CAR-1][CAR-2]{7}{blue}
        \AcotX[CAR-1-front][CAR-2-front]{2?}{blue}
        \AcotY[CAR-1][CAR-4]{2}{red}
                
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


How can I draw arc arrows between machines?

@mzn , I have updated something above with an example that may contain what you are looking for...

A command \mzncar is defined. It takes 2 arguments. The first argument is a coordinate used to shift the car. This argument is optional with default value (0,0). The second argument is the color.
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\mzncar}[2][(0,0)]{
\begin{scope}[shift={#1}]
\shade[top color=#2, bottom color=white, shading angle=135, draw=black, rounded corners=1.2ex, very thick] (1.5,.5) -- ++(0,1) -- ++(1,0.3) -- ++(3,0) -- ++(1,0) -- ++(0,-1.3) -- (1.5,.5) -- cycle;
\draw[very thick, rounded corners=0.5ex, fill=black!20!blue!20!white, thick] (2.5,1.8) -- ++(1,0.7) -- ++(1.6,0) -- ++(0.6,-0.7) -- (2.5,1.8);
\draw[thick] (4.2,1.8) -- (4.2,2.5);
\draw[fill=gray!50,thick] (2.75,.5) circle[radius=.5];
\draw[fill=gray!50,thick] (5.5,.5) circle[radius=.5];
\draw[fill=gray!80,semithick] (2.75,.5) circle[radius=.4];
\draw[fill=gray!80,semithick] (5.5,.5) circle[radius=.4];
\end{scope}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\mzncar{red}
\mzncar[(6,0)]{green}
\mzncar[(3,-3)]{blue}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



You can always create a \pic based of some part of your code which makes it easy to reuse it:
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    pics/my car/.style={
        code={
            \tikzset{my car/.cd, #1}
            \shade[my car/car color, shading angle={135},
                draw=black, rounded corners=1.2ex, very thick] 
                (1.5,.5) -- ++(0,1) -- ++(1,0.3) --  ++(3,0) -- ++(1,0) 
                    -- ++(0,-1.3) -- (1.5,.5) -- cycle;
            \draw[very thick, rounded corners=0.5ex, fill=black!20!blue!20!white, thick]
                (2.5,1.8) -- ++(1,0.7) -- ++(1.6,0) -- ++(0.6,-0.7) -- (2.5,1.8);
            \draw[thick] (4.2,1.8) -- (4.2,2.5);
            \draw[fill=gray!50, thick] 
                (2.75,.5) circle[radius=.5cm]
                (5.5,.5) circle[radius=.5cm];
            \draw[fill=gray!80, semithick] 
                (2.75,.5) circle[radius=.4cm]
                (5.5,.5) circle[radius=.4cm];
        }
    },
    my car/car color/.style={
        top color=red, bottom color=white
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pic {my car};    

\pic at (0,-3) {my car={car color/.append style={top color=blue}}};    

\pic[xscale=-1] at (14,-1.5) 
    {my car={car color/.append style={top color=green!50!black}}};    
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



You can also place coordinates in your \pic and use these to connect different \pics:
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    pics/my car/.style={
        code={
            \tikzset{my car/.cd, #1}
            \shade[my car/car color, shading angle={135},
                draw=black, rounded corners=1.2ex, very thick] 
                (1.5,.5) -- ++(0,1) -- ++(1,0.3) --  ++(3,0) -- ++(1,0) 
                    -- ++(0,-1.3) -- (1.5,.5) -- cycle;
            \draw[very thick, rounded corners=0.5ex, fill=black!20!blue!20!white, thick]
                (2.5,1.8) -- ++(1,0.7) -- ++(1.6,0) -- ++(0.6,-0.7) -- (2.5,1.8);
            \draw[thick] (4.2,1.8) -- (4.2,2.5);
            \draw[fill=gray!50, thick] 
                (2.75,.5) circle[radius=.5cm]
                (5.5,.5) circle[radius=.5cm];
            \draw[fill=gray!80, semithick] 
                (2.75,.5) circle[radius=.4cm]
                (5.5,.5) circle[radius=.4cm];
            \coordinate (-front) at (1.5,1);
            \coordinate (-back) at (6.5,1);
            \coordinate (-top) at (4.25,2.5);
            \coordinate (-bottom) at (4.25,0);
        }
    },
    my car/car color/.style={
        top color=red, bottom color=white
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pic (car 1) at (0,0) {my car};    

\pic (car 2) at (10,0) {my car={car color/.append style={top color=blue}}};    

\draw[<-, shorten <=5pt, shorten >=5pt, ultra thick] 
    (car 1-back) -- (car 2-front);

\draw[<-, shorten <=5pt, shorten >=5pt, ultra thick] 
    (car 1-top) to[out=90, in=90] (car 2-top);
 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



.I don't know how to draw this figure. can you help me please?

@mzn I would think that my answer is self-contained. Where do you need help with?

I have edited my question. I have added my figure to my question

I don't know how to draw this figure. can you help me please?

@mzn Please keep your original question, otherwise it is not possible for others to understand in which way the answers are related to the question. Please revert your question to its original form: You may then ask a new question or add an update to your original question.

@
Jasper Habicht I want the output of my code to be exactly like the figure I sent. But I don't know if, for example, my arrows will be exactly like the shape or the shape of the cars

@mzn Sorry, but your question is now totally different from what it was in the beginning. I suggest that you revert your question to its original and ask a new question.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
